# Asp Mvc3 webgrid Paging and Filtering by ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I Have a little problem with WebGrid control for Asp.Net MVC3. What I want is to perform a search view using ajax and webgrid; something like this:

Search Criteria  ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Subject: ***_*__*_*_**

Task Type: ***_*____**

SUBMIT SEARCH

---

WebGrid withPaging

.

When I click the button search it call the HTTPost action by ajax and apply the search criteria; however when I try to do paging it goes to the HTTPGet action; in this way, the filter according to the search criteria doesn't execute.

I put the grid inside a partial view; there is the code:

```
    @model IEnumerable<MVC3.Models.Task>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 2, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
    grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: 3, autoSortAndPage: true);
    grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All);
    @grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Assign Notifications", "AssignNotifications", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column("Subject"),
            grid.Column("Comment"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status", format: (item) => item.TaskStatu.Name),
            grid.Column(columnName: "StartDate", header: "Start Date", format: (item) => item.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Deadline", header: "Dead Line", format: (item) => item.Deadline.ToString("MM/dd/yyy"))
            )
    );
}
```

And my Index view looks like:

```
@model MVC3.ViewModel.TaskSearchViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Task Index</h2>
<hr />
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "myGrid" }))
{
    <div id="Filters">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Search criteria</legend>
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Subject)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Subject, new { style = "width: 255px;" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.TaskTypeId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TaskTypeId, Model.GetTaskTypesSelectList(), "Select", new { style = "width: 260px;" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ResponsableId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ResponsableId, Model.GetResponsablesSelectList(), "Select", new { style = "width: 260px;" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.StatusId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StatusId, Model.GetStatusSelectList(), "Select", new { style = "width: 260px;" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("page")
    <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Search" />
}
<br />
<div id="myGrid">
    @Html.Partial("_TaskSearchResult", Model.ResultTask)
</div>
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Create new Task", "NewTask")
```

So if anyone know how to solve my problem I'll be grateful.

Greeting
Arturo

Comment: I have the same problem - any luck? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999390/mvc-3-webgrid-paging-doesnt-return-orginal-search-results

Comment: Here is a solution I used.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1742017.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're replacing the grid each time you click the next page link. Maybe use it something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC3.Models.Task>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 2, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
    grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: 3, autoSortAndPage: true);
    grid.Pager(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All);
<div id="myGrid">
    @grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Assign Notifications", "AssignNotifications", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TaskId })),
            grid.Column("Subject"),
            grid.Column("Comment"),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status", format: (item) => item.TaskStatu.Name),
            grid.Column(columnName: "StartDate", header: "Start Date", format: (item) => item.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyy")),
            grid.Column(columnName: "Deadline", header: "Dead Line", format: (item) => item.Deadline.ToString("MM/dd/yyy"))
            )
    );
</div>
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help to pass the filter criteria back?  The grid generates the URL to call which includes the sort column, sort direction and page number (if its the pager) so you would need to augment this in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the grid generates an onclick call for each pager item (and column header) couldn't you just use jQuery to replace default values with a call to an Ajax method that passes the form back?