# MVC 3 WebGrid Paging doesn't return orginal search results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I have a search page with which on load fills a webgrid. My issue is with paging.
On load I fill the grid with "Non published" articles (there are none in this case).
Then I search for "Currently Published) and get 3 rows.

Now I have 3 pages (I set paging to one row per page for testing purposes).
The first time it searches - it gets the right answers in the grid,a nd lets say there are 2 pages.

If I click the 2 to go to the second page - the grid fills with the criteria of the load - which is Non Published of which there are none. I see that I am not going back to the HttpPost action on the page click - so I am not sure why it does this.

You can see I have an initial load called Admin
and a Post called Admin(FormCollection values)
On both I set the defaults back to "Not Published"

```
        public ActionResult Admin()
        {

            var menus =
            (
                 from p in db.Menus.ToList()
                 where p.ParentID == 0
                 orderby p.Order ascending
                 select p.Name
            );
            ViewBag.Menus = new SelectList(menus, "Home");

            string[] publishedStatuses = new string[3] 
                   { "NOT PUBLISHED", "EXPIRED ALREADY", "CURRENTLY PUBLISHED"}; 
            ViewBag.Published = new SelectList(publishedStatuses, "NOT PUBLISHED");

            var articles =
            (
                    from p in db.Articles.ToList()
                    where p.PublishToWeb == false && p.Menu == "Home"                  
                    select p
             );

            }
            return View(articles);
        }              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the link you're clicking to page will call the Admin controller action again, and since you're not receiving any parameters it will do the initial search again.

If you change the action method as:

```
public ActionResult Admin(int? page)
{
   //Your code here
}
```

You will get the page number from the web grid and can use that in your search. To enable filtering and searchgin, have a look at this blog post:

http://www.elylucas.net/post/Using-a-grid-that-can-sort-page-and-filter-in-AspNet-MVC3e28093Part-1e28093Using-the-WebGrid-WebHelper.aspx

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to pass my full code - I have a  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Admin(FormCollection values)
        { which returns the articles to the view filtered by the parameters in ViewBag.Published }

Comment: The second page click gives me the results of Not Published which is the default for thje dropdown. It never passes thru Admin post function so I don't know how it correctly gets that record(s) but it does.

Comment: The seond click has it calling Admin not Admin post so that is why it gets the orginal default set. How can I get it to call Admin Post on teh paging click?

Comment: Since the paging is done via GET (the click on the link) you can't have it to call the adminPost method. You could do this by attaching a jQuery eventhandler to the paging links like, $('.ajaxGrid table tfoot tr a').live('click', updateGrid);
 
 });

Comment: Yes I see it is by the get now - could you elaborate - I have no idea of how to start on your suggestion? Thanks