# MVC Razor & AJAX paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there a way in which I can construct a MVC page such that, if required, I can pull the contents of it without the entire HTML frame.  I.e. I want to be able to, if required, pull just the contents (for AJAX Paging) without the refreshing the entire page, but I want that to be possible too

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ViewDevice";
}

<h2>ViewDevice</h2>
```

Comment: I used webgrid http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949003/asp-mvc3-webgrid-paging-and-filtering-by-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partial view to implement reusable part of a view and render it in any view you want like this `@Html.Partial("_ViewDevice")`.

For more information on how to create a partial view see [here](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m3-views&mode=live&clip=6&course=mvc4-building) and [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/105/ASP.NET-MVC-Partial-Views-and-Strongly-Typed-Custom-ViewModels).

Comment: How would I get that view from jQuery? If I simply do `$.get("url")` will it work?

Comment: Yes, but with some modification, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial thats easy and quick:

http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/05/30/asp-net-mvc-simple-server-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

check it out: https://github.com/kibiluzbad/Ifa

sample online demo: ifademo.apphb.com/

hope it helps